# How to specific variable value inside "" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code

```
success: function(result) {
    var htmlString = '';
    htmlString+= '<div class=\"row mgt45 bg-delete\"><div class=\"col-sm-5\"><div class=\"p-relative\"><img id=\"logoImg\" src=\"result.image\" width=\"100%\"><button id=\"result.id\" class=\"change-img topleft\"   data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\"><i class=\"fa fa-camera\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> 画像</button></div> </div><div class=\"col-sm-7 corp-office\"><h2 id=\"title_result.id\" class=\"changeableFacility\" contenteditable=\"true\">result.title</h2><p id=\"content1_result.id\" class=\"changeableFacility\" contenteditable=\"true\">result.content1</p><p id=\"result.content2\" class=\"changeableFacility\" contenteditable=\"true\">result.content2</p></div><span id=\"delete_result.id\" href=\"\" class=\"btn-delete\"><i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></span> </div>';

    $('#addItem').before(htmlString);
},
```

How can I store `result.id`, `result.image` as a variable instead of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ECMAScript 2015's [Template String Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var id = 5;
var image = "myimage.jpg";
alert(` <div id=\"${id}\">`);
alert(` <img src=\"${image}\">`)
```

Comment: Good explanation, congrats!

Comment: Still not working `htmlString+= '<div id=\"${id}\"` id inside \"\", have problem there?

Comment: its not quotes ( ' ' ) Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)

Comment: Thank for answer, I save 2h : ) instead of use operation in string. thanks again.

Comment: @ChungDo glad it helped

Comment: when i run in edge browser SCRIPT1014: Invalid character `, you have fix this problem? Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Your variables right now are just a string. To make the value of the variable show up in a string you must chop the string into piece's and use the addition operator to add in the variable like so.

```
var imaVariable = "I'll get added into the string.";

var newString = "This is a string" + imaVariable + "This is also a string";
```